# Duplicate class entry when adding AAR and JAR

Tags: android, jar, aar

I have a `Java` library which gets packaged in a `JAR` and gets put inside an `Android Library`. The `Android Library` then gets packaged as an `AAR` and gets put inside an `Android app`.

When trying to launch the `Android` app, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory;
```

SLF4J is a dependency within the `Java Library`. This shows us that the Android AAR didn't bring along the dependencies from the Java library (I learnt this is the case by Googling the issue).

So - I then decided that if the dependencies aren't brought along, I'll add the `Java Library` *and* the `Android Library` to the `Android app`.

When I now run the `Android app`, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/.../AuthenticationOptions$1.class
```

Either way doesn't work.

**`Android app` Gradle**:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'android-library', ext:'aar')
    compile files('libs/java-library.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: If you're any 3rd party library contains SLF4J  then you don't need to add externally in build.gradle

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: Where is your build.gradle ? post it

Comment: @MD I've added the `Android app`'s Gradle file.

Comment: This may help you about adding JAR in android studio app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Comment: @MD Following the tutorial works, however, when I get the `Android Library` which now has the `Java Library` added as a `JAR` Project, it fails to copy over the dependencies...